# How can I use matlab source code in labview without matlab?

Tags: matlab, dll, labview, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I found mathscript can do this,but it seem too slow.
So I want to use matlab to create a dll file used by labview,but all information I can find just how dll could used in C++,but C++ also must use the .lib file ,I am concerned labview could not use lib. file.

So can I use the .dll in labvew,and how?Is there anyother way to use matlab source code in labview without matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to purchase the [MATLAB Compiler](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler.html) which is quite expensive unless you are a student.

You can also call the MATLAB application (if it's installed) using the MATLAB Script Node (which is different than Mathscript) - see [here](https://www.ni.com/docs/en-US/bundle/labview/page/lvhelp/labview_help.html)

Another alternative is [Python's Numpy](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users) which I personally picked up quickly coming from a MATLAB background. If you want to go down that route I can give you further advice on how to integrate with LabVIEW.

Comment: Thanks,actually,I make a matlab program that would be used by many people and some of them didn't have matlab.I think MATLAB Compiler is all I need.

Comment: Great. Please make the question as answered if you don't need anything else.